# How to print something specific if something random is chosen?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, if-statement, random

I have a program that prints things randomly from lists. How do I make the program print something for the choice it made.
For example:

```
choices=["X","Y"]
print random.choice(choices)
if random.choice == "X":
    print "XX"
elif random.choice == "Y":
    print "YY"
```

Comment: `random.choice()` is a method, not the result of picking something at random. Compare to the actual return value of `random.choice()` **stored in a variable** (so you don't make two different random choices).

Comment: This is otherwise **no different** from comparing to something that wasn't random (like `foo = 'X'`, then `if foo == 'X':`). Why not try to make that work first, then replace the fixed value with a random choice?

Comment: You already know how to use a variable; `choice` is a variable you assigned something to. Just do the same with the result of `random.choice()` (*instead* of sending the result to `print`).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you printed the choice you made to the screen, and then compared *the `random.choice` function to the possible choices*. You need to instead store the choice made, and then compare that to the choices.

```
import random

choices = ["X","Y"]
choice = random.choice(choices)
print choice

if choice == "X":
    print "XX" 
elif choice == "Y":
    print "YY"
```